# in K8s run python script to go into pod directly

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, kubernetes

The following command can run in K8s correctly

```
kubectl exec -n nginx-ingress $(kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress -o wide -LhaRole | grep nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -it -- /bin/bash
```

if I put it into a python script as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.run('kubectl exec -n nginx-ingress $(kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress -o wide -LhaRole | grep nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -it -- /bin/bash', shell=True)
```

the result shows SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Can anyone help me to correct it and let it run?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
[root@k8s-master temp]# kubectl exec -n nginx-ingress $(kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress -o wide -LhaRole | grep nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -it -- /bin/bash
nginx@nginx-ingress-b9fcfbb59-cn647:/$
nginx@nginx-ingress-b9fcfbb59-cn647:/$ exit
exit
[root@k8s-master temp]#
[root@k8s-master temp]# ./k8s.py
  File "/home/jin/temp/./k8s.py", line 9
    subprocess.run('kubectl exec -n nginx-ingress $(kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress -o wide -LhaRole | grep nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -it -- /bin/bash', shell=True)
                                                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@k8s-master temp]#
[root@k8s-master temp]#
```

Comment: Try `subprocess.run("command ...".split(), ...) the `split` is key since you need a list of the command's components.
But probably this is a duplicate question if that's your issue..

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  I'd use `kubectl exec` sparingly, since whatever it does intrinsically only affects one replica of a Deployment and whatever changes you make will be lost when the Pod is deleted (not necessarily under your control).  You may find it easier to just run the command you want rather than try to interact with a shell.  I'd try really hard to avoid `subprocess.run(shell=True)`, which will mean introspecting the Kubernetes cluster and running this exec command in separate calls.

Comment: Just in terms of Python syntax, though: your `awk` parameter is a single-quoted string, but you have that inside a single-quoted Python string.  If you change the quotes around the first parameter to double quotes, `"kubectl ... | awk '...' ..."`, you'll avoid the Python SyntaxError.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what you’ve shared, I believe you encounter a syntax error because your script uses single quotes both inside and outside the command string. In Python, this prematurely ends the string.

Note that the `-it` flags in the `kubectl exec` command are used for interactive terminals, which may not behave as expected within your Python script.

I suggest you modify your script to surround the command with triple single quotes (`'''`), as this way, you can include single quotes inside the string without needing to escape them. You can learn more about using quotes [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/single-double-and-triple-quotes-in-python-7ceea990baf).

Also I removed the `-it` flags from the `kubectl exec` command to ensure the command can be executed in your script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

command = '''kubectl exec -n nginx-ingress $(kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress -o wide | grep nginx-ingress | grep Running | awk '{print $1}') -- /bin/bash'''

subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Give this a go and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, very helpful and it works. Have a nice weekend. PS: The link you gave  as reference is not working, could you give it again?

Comment: Glad it worked. Also, I have modified the link. You can check again.

Comment: Many thanks, yes, the link works we well 